# play audio range in html5

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I would like to be able to have buttons that can play certain audio ranges from a larger file.  Something like:

```
<button onclick="playClip('http://blah/source1.mp3', 2.5, 3.0, 1.0)">Play clip 1</button>
<button onclick="playClip('http://blah/source2.mp3', 10.0, 2.0, 0.5)">Play clip 2 slow</button>
```

where playClip has a pattern like this:

```
function playClip(src, startOffset, length, rate) {
  // What to put here?
}
```

Or instead of a length, an ending offset.

Can some one point me to code that can do that, or help me write it?  The closest I could find is https://gist.github.com/remy/753003/download# but I need different sized clips, from possibly different files, and with a playback rate specified.  I'm afraid I've limited experience with Javascript.

I'm trying to replace a Silverlight app that does this.

Thanks.

-John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extract of my current code, which uses both the audio control's events and timeout to make sure the audio stops. There's a reference to a volume slider you might need to trim.

```
var jt_audioControl;
var jt_audioSource;
var jt_audioFiles;
var jt_audioFileIndex;
var jt_audioFile;
var jt_audioStartTime;
var jt_audioEndTime;
var jt_audioPlaybackRate;
var jt_audioTimeoutHandle;
var jt_audioLink;
var jt_audioMimeType;
var jt_audioMediaType;
var jt_volumeSlider;

function jt_onAudioTimeUpdate() {
    if (jt_audioEndTime > 0.0) {
        if (jt_audioControl.currentTime >= jt_audioEndTime) {
            //alert('stopped: jt_audioControl.currentTime = ' + jt_audioControl.currentTime + ' jt_audioEndTime = ' + jt_audioEndTime);
            jt_audioControl.pause();
            //jt_audioStartTime = jt_audioEndTime = 0.0;
        }
    }
}

function jt_onAudioCanPlay() {
    jt_audioControl.pause();
    jt_audioControl.currentTime = jt_audioStartTime;
    jt_audioControl.defaultPlaybackRate = jt_audioPlaybackRate;
    jt_audioControl.playbackRate = jt_audioPlaybackRate;
    jt_audioControl.play();
    jt_audioControl.currentTime = jt_audioStartTime;
    jt_volumeSliderChanged();   // Set initial value to slider.
    var timeout = (((jt_audioEndTime - jt_audioStartTime)) / jt_audioPlaybackRate) * 1000;
    //alert('jt_audioEndTime = ' + jt_audioEndTime + ', timeout = ' + timeout);
    if (jt_audioEndTime > 0.0) {
        jt_audioTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(jt_onAudioEnded, timeout);
        //alert('jt_audioTimeoutHandle = ' + jt_audioTimeoutHandle);
    }
    else if (jt_audioTimeoutHandle != null) {
        clearTimeout(jt_audioTimeoutHandle);
        jt_audioTimeoutHandle = null;
    }
}

function jt_onAudioEnded() {
    //alert('ended called');
    if (jt_audioFiles == null)
        return;
    while (jt_audioControl.position < jt_audioControl.duration)
        ;
    jt_audioFileIndex = jt_audioFileIndex + 1;
    if (jt_audioFileIndex < jt_audioFiles.length) {
        jt_createAudio(jt_audioFiles[jt_audioFileIndex]);
    }
    else {
        jt_audioControl.pause();
        jt_audioFiles = null;
        jt_audioFileIndex = 0;
    }
}

function jt_onAudioError(e) {
    var msg;
    switch (e.target.error.code) {
        case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:
            msg = 'You aborted the video playback.';
            break;
        case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:
            msg = 'A network error caused the video download to fail part-way.';
            break;
        case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:
            msg = 'The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support.';
            break;
        case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            msg = 'The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.';
            break;
        default:
            msg = 'An unknown error occurred.';
            break;
    }
    alert('Error loading media: ' + msg + ' Media file: ' + jt_audioFile + ' MIME type: ' + jt_audioMimeType);
}

function jt_addSource(url) {
    var srcUrl;
    var doConvertCheck = false;
    var offset = url.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (offset == -1) {
        if (jt_audioSource == null) {
            jt_audioSource = document.createElement('source');
            jt_audioControl.appendChild(jt_audioSource);
        }
        jt_audioMimeType = 'audio/mpeg3';
        jt_audioMediaType = 'audio/mpeg3';
        jt_audioSource.type = jt_audioMediaType;
        jt_audioSource.src = url;
        jt_audioControl.load();
        return;
    }
    var base = url.substr(0, offset);
    var ext = url.substr(offset).toLowerCase();
    var newExt = ext;
    if (jt_audioControl.canPlayType('audio/mpeg3')) {
        jt_audioMimeType = 'audio/mpeg3';
        jt_audioMediaType = 'audio/mpeg3';
        if (ext != '.mp3')
            newExt = '-aa.mp3';
    }
    else if (jt_audioControl.canPlayType('audio/mpeg')) {
        jt_audioMimeType = 'audio/mpeg3';
        jt_audioMediaType = 'audio/mpeg';
        if (ext != '.mp3')
            newExt = '-aa.mp3';
    }
    else if (jt_audioControl.canPlayType('audio/mp3')) {
        jt_audioMimeType = 'audio/mpeg3';
        jt_audioMediaType = 'audio/mp3';
        if (ext != '.mp3')
            newExt = '-aa.mp3';
    }
    else if (jt_audioControl.canPlayType('audio/ogg')) {
        jt_audioMimeType = 'audio/ogg';
        jt_audioMediaType = 'audio/ogg';
        if (ext != '.ogg')
            newExt = '-aa.ogg';
    }
    else {
        alert('Sorry, can not play file: ' + url);
    }
    srcUrl = base + newExt;
    if (srcUrl.lastIndexOf('~', 0) === 0) {
        if (window.location.hostname == '') {
            srcUrl = srcUrl.substr(2);
        }
        else {
            var url = 'http://' + window.location.hostname;
            if (window.location.port.toString() != '')
                url = usrl + ':' + window.location.port.toString()
            srcUrl = url + srcUrl.substr(1);
        }
    }
    //alert('srcUrl = ' + srcUrl);
    if (jt_audioSource == null) {
        jt_audioSource = document.createElement('source');
        jt_audioControl.appendChild(jt_audioSource);
    }
    jt_audioSource.type = jt_audioMediaType;
    if (doConvertCheck) {
        jt_audioLink = "/ConvertCheck?path=" + srcUrl + "&" + "mimeType=" + jt_audioMimeType
        jt_audioSource.src = jt_audioLink;
    }
    else {
        jt_audioSource.src = srcUrl;
    }
    jt_audioControl.load();
}

function jt_extractTimeRange(url) {
    var rangeFieldIndex = url.lastIndexOf("#t");
    if (rangeFieldIndex >= 0) {
        var rangeString = url.substr(rangeFieldIndex + 2);
        var range = rangeString.split(',');
        jt_audioStartTime = parseFloat(range[0]);
        jt_audioEndTime = parseFloat(range[1]);
    }
    else {
        jt_audioStartTime = 0.0;
        jt_audioEndTime = 0.0;
        return url;
    }
    return url.substr(0, rangeFieldIndex);
}

function jt_createAudio(url) {
    url = jt_extractTimeRange(url);
    if (jt_audioControl == null) {
        jt_audioFile = url;
        jt_audioControl = new Audio();
        // The ontimeupdate handler seems to be called unreliably, so we'll use
        // setTimeout as well in the oncanplay handler.
        jt_audioControl.ontimeupdate = jt_onAudioTimeUpdate;
        jt_audioControl.onloadedmetadata = jt_onAudioCanPlay;
        jt_audioControl.onended = jt_onAudioEnded;
        jt_audioControl.onerror = jt_onAudioError;
        jt_addSource(url);
        // We'll let the oncanplay call play once loaded.
    }
    else if (jt_audioFile != url) {
        jt_audioFile = url;
        jt_addSource(url);
    }
    else {
        //jt_onAudioLoaded();
        jt_audioControl.load();
    }
}

function jt_playAudioFile(url) {
    jt_audioFiles = null;
    jt_audioFileIndex = 0;
    jt_audioStartTime = 0.0;
    jt_audioEndTime = 0.0;
    jt_audioPlaybackRate = 1.0;
    jt_createAudio(url);
}

function jt_playSlowAudioFile(url) {
    jt_audioFiles = null;
    jt_audioFileIndex = 0;
    jt_audioStartTime = 0.0;
    jt_audioEndTime = 0.0;
    jt_audioPlaybackRate = 0.5;
    jt_createAudio(url);
}

function jt_playAudioFileList(urls) {
    jt_audioFiles = urls;
    jt_audioFileIndex = 0;
    jt_audioStartTime = 0.0;
    jt_audioEndTime = 0.0;
    jt_audioPlaybackRate = 1.0;
    if ((urls != null) && (urls.length > 0)) {
        jt_createAudio(urls[0]);
    }
}

function jt_playSlowAudioFileList(urls) {
    jt_audioFiles = urls;
    jt_audioFileIndex = 0;
    jt_audioStartTime = 0.0;
    jt_audioEndTime = 0.0;
    jt_audioPlaybackRate = 0.5;
    if ((urls != null) && (urls.length > 0)) {
        jt_createAudio(urls[0]);
    }
}

function jt_playAudioFileSegment(url, startTime, endTime) {
    jt_audioFiles = null;
    jt_audioFileIndex = 0;
    url = url + '#t' + startTime.toString() + ',' + endTime.toString();
    jt_audioPlaybackRate = 1.0;
    jt_createAudio(url);
}

function jt_playSlowAudioFileSegment(url, startTime, endTime) {
    jt_audioFiles = null;
    jt_audioFileIndex = 0;
    url = url + '#t' + startTime.toString() + ',' + endTime.toString();
    jt_audioPlaybackRate = 0.5;
    jt_createAudio(url);
}

function jt_stopAudio() {
    if (jt_audioControl != null)
        jt_audioControl.pause();
}

function jt_volumeSliderChanged() {
    if (jt_volumeSlider == null) {
        jt_volumeSlider = document.getElementById('volumeSlider');
        if (jt_volumeSlider == null)
            return;
    }
    var value = jt_volumeSlider.value;
    if (jt_audioControl != null)
        jt_audioControl.volume = value / 10;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Common/SetUserOptionAjax?key=AudioVolume&value=" + value.toString(),
        type: "POST"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Either use [Media Fragments URI](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/#naming-time) syntax:

```
var src,
    startOffset,
    endOffset,
    playbackRate,
    audio = new Audio(src + '#t=' + startOffset + ',' + endOffset);

audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  audio.playbackRate = playbackRate;
  audio.play();
};
```

or `timeupdate` event:

```
var audio = new Audio( ... ),
    startOffset,
    endOffset,
    playbackRate;

audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  audio.playbackRate = playbackRate;
  audio.currentTime = startOffset;
  audio.play();
};

audio.ontimeupdate = function() {
  if (audio.currentTime >= endOffset) {
    audio.pause();
  }
};
```

References:

- [Specifying playback range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range)
- [Jumping to time offsets in HTML5 video](http://gingertech.net/2009/08/19/jumping-to-time-offsets-in-videos/)

Comment: For some reason, the ontimeupdate event is unreliable, at least for the first play click, meaning it might not get called at all, until the audio ends, or is inaccurate, meaning the clip overplays.  What worked best for me was the setTimeout suggestion in the first reference above.  Thank you so much for unblocking me on this!

Comment: well which one should i use?

Comment: @jtsoftware Looks like the first reference no longer shows the setTimeout suggestion you reference.  This is 5 years too late but in the off chance you see this could you post your solution?

Comment: @toppsdown I don't remember where the setTimeout suggestion came from, but I've updated my later answer with an extract of my current code which uses both the audio control handlers and setTimeout.